# Function User.getUserId() in Cloud endpoint api returns null for a user object that is not null

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a problem with getting the userid for a cloud endpoint method. I have used oauth2 authentication in my android client and passed the credentials to my service. The below is similar to what my method looks like (simplified to make it more clear).

I note that [issue 8848](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8848#makechanges) for python seems to be very similar to this problem.

Is the same issue a problem in java api as well? The method

```
public SuccessCode doSomething(WireFormat wire, User user){
    log.info("User id: "+user.getUserId());
    log.info("Federated identity: "+user.getFederatedIdentity());
    log.info("Email address: "+user.getEmail());
}
```

will show null for federated identity and userId even though credentials in android client have had oauth2 authentication performed. The email address shows up correctly in the log. This is all on a deployed application btw.

Anybody have any other suggestions as to what is wrong? Any known workarounds for the issue? I have followed the method suggested in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_android#making-authenticated-calls to set up my android client.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct that issue 8848 is the same cause. The underlying issue is language-agnostic and affects both runtimes. At the moment you shouldn't expect the user ID field populated in a `User` object passed in via method argument in Endpoints.

A super suboptimal workaround is to persist the `User` object to the datastore and read it back. The re-read object will have the user ID included.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the workaround I guess. At least I know and can wait for a bugfix now.

Comment: It seems that this is still not fixed. I have a cloud endpoints backend that returns null whenever I call getUserId. Although, is there any need to use the user id? Email is also unique and I dont think its possible for a user to change their email address.

Comment: Any confidence in getting this working?  Trying to decide to implement this bad work around, or go with using email as key.

Answer (score -1):

I followed the same document reference in the question and had the same exact problem.

Finally got the Endpoints working with OAuth2 by doing the following:

There was an update for Google Play Services which I updated to; now on version 15 (Android SDK).

The endpoint documentation was updated to state that you should enable the Google Plus APIs for your application, even if you just using userinfo.email scope for your app engine endpoints.   I did this via the Cloud Console.

Also, finally, there was a new note stating that OAuth2 does not work from the emulator.   I confirmed this.  I still get the null user error from an Android Emulator, even when pointing to the production app engine.  So I can still only test endpoints from a real device.

I was able to confirm that I needed all three of the above steps.

Comment: Could you please provide links to mentioned statements? I have started developing app using endpoint but I never seen anything about enabling Google+ API.

Comment: This solution seems irrelevant to the question. The problem stated is in the backend appengine/cloud endpoints. What you're describing is in the frontend android code.