# Get the Google user ID in Endpoints-Android project

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is a bug, discussed here [Function User.getUserId() in Cloud endpoint api returns null for a user object that is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171225/function-user-getuserid-in-cloud-endpoint-api-returns-null-for-a-user-object-t) but since I cannot comment yet...

One cannot get the user_id but only the email of the User. The solution seems to be "to persist the User object to the datastore and read it back. The re-read object will have the user ID included.".

But how to persist the User in the datastore since this class is not a db.Model?