# Google Endpoints API + Chrome Extension returns None for endpoints.get_current_user().user_id()

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-chrome-extension, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints

I am developing Google App Engine application written in Python and using Endpoints API. In conjunction, I am writing a Chrome Extension to interact with the Endpoints API. I've been running into lots of issues with the Endpoints API and authorization. Currently, here is my setup:

### Endpoints API (Python)

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
from protorpc import message_types
from protorpc import remote

ALLOWED_CLIENT_IDS = ['client_id_from_google_api_console',
                      endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID]

@endpoints.api(name='my_api',version='v1', description='My API',
               allowed_client_ids=ALLOWED_CLIENT_IDS)
class MyApi(remote.Service):

    @endpoints.method(message_types.VoidMessage, DeviceListResponse,
                      name='user.device.list', path='user/device/list', 
                      http_method='GET')
    def user_device_list(self, request):
        current_user = endpoints.get_current_user()
        if current_user is None:
            raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('You must authenticate first.')
        if current_user.user_id() is None:
            raise endpoints.NotFoundException("Your user id was not found.")

        return DeviceListResponse(devices=[]) #Hypothetically return devices

api_service = endpoints.api_server([MyApi], restricted=False)
```

### Google API Console

The JS origins include:
chrome-extensions://chrome_app_id

### CHROME EXTENSION (JS)

```
var apiRoot = "https://my_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/api";
var clientID = "client_id_from_google_api_console";
var oauthScopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"];
var responseType = "token id_token";

//Helper method to log to the console
function l(o){console.log(o);}

function oauthSignin(mode) {
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientID, scope: oauthScopes,
    immediate: mode, response_type: responseType}, function() {
        var request = gapi.client.oauth2.userinfo.get();
        request.execute(function(resp) {
            authenticated = !resp.code;
            if(authenticated) {
                var token = gapi.auth.getToken();
                token.access_token = token.id_token;
                gapi.auth.setToken(token);
                l("Successfully authenticated. Loading device list");
                gapi.client.my_api.user.device.list({}).execute(function(resp) {
                    if(resp.code) {
                        l("Response from device list: " + resp.message);
                    }
                    l(resp);
                });
            }
        });
    });
}


//This get's called when the page and js library has loaded.
function jsClientLoad() {
    l("JS Client Libary loaded. Now loading my_api and oauth2 APIs.");
    var apisToLoad;
    var callback = function() {
        if (--apisToLoad == 0) {
            l("APIs have loaded.")
            oauthSignin(true);
        } else {
            l("Waiting for " + apisToLoad + " API" + (apisToLoad>1?"s":"") + " to load.");
        }
    }

    apisToLoad = 2; // must match number of calls to gapi.client.load()
    gapi.client.load('my_api', 'v1', callback, apiRoot);
    gapi.client.load('oauth2', 'v2', callback);
}
```

### Result

Now that I have shown the main chunk of my code (note, I had to change it a bit to make sense without uploading entire code), if I go to the Google API Explorer and run that method, I get a 200 response. If I run it in the Chrome Extension, I get a 404 code with the message "Your user id was not found.".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's unclear why/when this ever results in a `200`; it should not. As mentioned in [Function User.getUserId() in Cloud endpoint api returns null for a user object that is not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171225), this is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8848).

## TLDR;

The `user_id` will **never** be populated in the result returned from `endpoints.get_current_user()`. A workaround exists: by storing the user object in the datastore and then retrieving it (with a new get, if you are using `ndb`), the `user_id()` value will be populated.

You should strongly consider using the Google Profile ID associated with the account instead of the App Engine User ID.

## History/Explanation:

`endpoints` is meant to be used with both Bearer tokens and ID tokens (for Android). ID tokens are a special type of JWT (JSON web token) signed in conjunction with on device crypto. As a result, parsing the user from these tokens can only determine the information encoded in that token (see [Cloud endpoints oauth2 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410013) for more info about that).

Since these tokens are minted by a generic Google Auth provider (OAuth 2.0) outside of App Engine, the App Engine User ID is not known/shared by this service. As a result, it is **never** possible to populate the `user_id()` when an ID token is used to sign the request.

When a standard Bearer token is used (which would be fine for your Chrome application), the App Engine [OAuth API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/oauth/overview) is used. When the OAuth API calls

```
oauth.get_current_user(some_scope)
```

(where `oauth` is `google.appengine.api.oauth`), the

```
oauth.oauth_api._maybe_call_get_oauth_user(_scope=None)
```

[method](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/oauth/oauth_api.py?r=345#156) is called. This makes an [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) to a shared App Engine layer which provides a service that is able to get the current user from the token. In **this case**, the `user_id()` of the returned user **WILL** be set, however, the user value is not kept around for `endpoints.get_current_user`, only the email and the auth domain are.

## Another Workaround:

The `oauth.get_current_user()` call is only expensive **IF** it makes the RPC. The `_maybe_call_get_oauth_user` method stores the value from the last call, so calling `oauth.get_current_user()` a second time  will incur no network/speed overhead other than the few nanoseconds to lookup a value from a Python `dict`.

This is crucial because `endpoints.get_current_user()` uses a call to `oauth.get_current_user()` to determine the Bearer token user, so if you wanted to call it again, you'd worry about that performance.

If you know you'll never be using ID tokens or can easily determine those situations, you could change your code to just call both:

```
endpoints_user = endpoints.get_current_user()
if endpoints_user is None:
    raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException(...)

oauth_user = oauth.get_current_user(known_scope)
if oauth_user is None or oauth_user.user_id() is None:
    # This should never happen
    raise endpoints.NotFoundException(...)
```

**NOTE**: We still must call `endpoints.get_current_user()` because it always makes sure that our token has been minted only for one of the specific scopes we've allowed and for one of the specific client IDs we have whitelisted to talk to our application.

**NOTE**: The value `known_scope` will vary depending on which of your possible scopes matches the token. Your list of scopes will be looped through in one of the `endpoints.get_current_user()` [helper methods](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/endpoints/users_id_token.py?r=345#347), and if this succeeds, the final matching scope will be stored as `os.getenv('OAUTH_LAST_SCOPE')`. I would strongly recommend using this value for `known_scope`.

## Better Alternative:

As mentioned, the App Engine User ID simply can't be implied from an ID token (at current), however, the [Google Profile ID](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login#obtaininguserprofileinformation) can be used instead of the App Engine User ID. (This ID is often seen as the Google+ ID, though this is consistent across many services.)

To make sure this value is associated with your Bearer **OR** ID tokens, make sure you also request one of the non-`userinfo.email` scopes associated with the [`userinfo` API](http://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/oauth2/v2/oauth2.userinfo.get):

- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email`
- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

(This list of scopes current as of this writing on May 20, 2013.)

Similarly as with the App Engine User ID in the Bearer token case, this Google Profile ID is discarded by `endpoints.get_current_user()`, **BUT** it is available for both kinds of tokens.

The `get_google_plus_user_id()` [method](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-picturesque-python/blob/833c784239ae97f3c78239ddf1fbb98346c96f4a/auth_util.py#L26) which is part of the [`appengine-picturesque-python`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-picturesque-python) sample patches one of the `endpoints.get_current_user()` helper methods to keep this data around and allows you to use this value without having to repeat the expensive network calls used to validate the Bearer or ID token from the request.

Comment: I am attempting to associate a signed in user with a user from my app. Using the `email()` won't work because my application wouldn't know when a user changes their email. Retrieving some sort of `user_id` guarantees I know who that user is since the `user_id` never changes.

My confusion comes when thinking of other apps like MightyText. How do they go about authenticating users and associating when I log in with who I am in their Datastore? I know they use oauth (Chrome source code), so maybe they have the RPC overhead?

Comment: Like I mentioned, using `endpoints.get_current_user()` is a "subset" of `oauth.get_current_user()` for most purposes. If you use the Google Profile ID and the suggested fix from [`auth_util.py`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-picturesque-python/blob/833c784239ae97f3c78239ddf1fbb98346c96f4a/auth_util.py), you'll be in great shape with a unique ID which does not change.

Comment: Is there also a working example (e.g. for Another Workaround and for the Better Alternative) in Java?

Comment: Is it possible to do what `get_google_plus_user_id()` does in Java?

Comment: I'm not sure, I've been away from it for awhile since leaving Google. It's very likely. Have you checked the source code? Most of it is done at the RPC/Network level rather than software.

Comment: I found out that it is possible to inject the `HttpServletRequest` into my api methods. So my method for getting the google+ user id is: 1) checking that the injectected `Ùser`isn't `null` 2) get the token out of the request header 3) decode the token and get the id.

Comment: Sounds great! I recall this behavior from when I used to work on Endpoints.

Comment: @gabriel could you provide a code snippet to illustrate how you got this working in java?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone is here since 1.8.6 and is still trying to use the `auth_util.py` work around to return the Google profile id. `endpoints.token_id` now has two methods depending on if the user is on the development server or not.

When on Google's servers the flow returns the `oauth_user` and does not hit the tokeninfo endpoint. Therefore no token info is saved in `auth_util.py`. However, on the dev server it does hit the tokeninfo endpoint so works as expected.

For me the easiest way to solve this was just to monkey patch  `endpoints.token_id._is_local_dev` and set that to always be true.

Comment: But this results in an extra round trip and wastes network when in production. Bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I have just recently run into this headache. However, after some testing it appears that with 1.9.2 `user.user_id()` returns `None` on the local development server. However, if you deploy, it will return a value. Not sure if this is the App Engine ID or Google+ ID though. Anyway to find out?

However, given the documentation, I assume the ID it does return is safe to use for persistent    records.