# Is there a way to check if the user is an admin in AppEngine Cloud Endpoints

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using AppEngine Cloud Endpoints with the Javascript client and Google+ Sign In, I am using `endpoints.get_current_user()`. Is there a way to check if the user is an AppEngine admin? Similar to `users.is_current_user_admin()` in users API.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [Google Endpoints API + Chrome Extension returns None for endpoints.get_current_user().user_id()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661109) for a long description of the difference between ID tokens and Bearer tokens when performing auth.

If you aren't using an Android application, you can freely use Bearer tokens and not have to worry about some of the limitations of ID tokens.

Right next `get_current_user()`, the `oauth` library provides the `oauth.is_current_user_admin()` method. Exactly as `get_current_user()`, [this method calls](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/oauth/oauth_api.py?r=345#99) `_maybe_call_get_oauth_user` and then checks a simple environment variable.

As mentioned in the other answer:

> The `oauth.get_current_user()` call is only expensive **IF** it makes
>   the RPC. The `_maybe_call_get_oauth_user` method stores the value from
>   the last call, so calling `oauth.get_current_user()` a second time 
>   will incur no network/speed overhead other than the few nanoseconds to
>   lookup a value from a Python `dict`.

So if you are only using Bearer tokens, you could do the following

```
from google.appengine.api import oauth
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints

...

endpoints_user = endpoints.get_current_user()
if endpoints_user is None:
    raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException(...)

is_admin = oauth.is_current_user_admin(known_scope)
if not is_admin:
    # Throw a 403 FORBIDDEN
    raise endpoints.ForbiddenException(...)
```