# How do you know if the current user is an admin with app engine cloud endpoints?

Tags: google-app-engine, admin, google-cloud-endpoints

I know the endpoints module has a `get_current_user` function, but as far as I know, the user object has no property or method to find out if the user is an admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752998/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-user-is-an-admin-in-appengine-cloud-endpoints) was very helpful to me. It requires that you use the google+ sign in button, but that's  a good temporary sollution. The reason I'd like to work something else out, is because I want to use this for admin console pages, in which case, the admin is already logged in to google, so having a google+ login button there looks weird.

An other way to implement this would be to make my own oauth system, where a script in the admin page makes a request to a a normal requesthandler, which requests if the user is an admin, and if so, returns a sort of admin token, which grants the user access to my endpoints methods. With every endpoints request, I'm already using such a token system in the user facing part of the application, because I can't use google accounts for the app. The token is only valid for a limited amount of time, and a limited number of requests.

Comment: You don't need Google+ Sign-In. You just need to use Bearer tokens and avoid ID tokens. Unfortunately, you must use ID tokens on Android.