# How to get at the request object when using endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm testing a method to reject requests to our GAE API if not providing a shared-id as discussed in my SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27195497/4102061). This involves using the hiddenProperty method suggested by [bossylobster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16803274/4102061).

My demo code on GAE looks like this:

```
import endpoints

from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsAliasProperty
from endpoints_proto_datastore.ndb import EndpointsModel
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
from protorpc import remote

DEFAULT_ORDER = 'created, sid'

class TestModel(EndpointsModel):
    _message_fields_schema = ('sid', 'a1', 'a2', 'created')
    a1 = ndb.StringProperty()
    a2 = ndb.StringProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

    def SidSet(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, basestring):
            raise TypeError('SID must be a string.')
        self.UpdateFromKey(ndb.Key(TestModel, value))

    @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=SidSet, required=True)
    def sid(self):
        if self.key is not None:
            return self.key.string_id()

    @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=EndpointsModel.OrderSet,
                            default=DEFAULT_ORDER)
    def order(self):
        return super(TestModel, self).order

@endpoints.api(name='demogaeapi', version='v1',       
               scopes=[endpoints.EMAIL_SCOPE],
               description='My Demo API')
class MyApi(remote.Service):

    @TestModel.method(http_method='GET',
                      path='testmodel/{sid}',
                      request_fields=('sid',),
                      name='testmodel.get')
    def testModelGet(self, test_model):

        appId,keytype = request.get_unrecognized_field_info('hiddenProperty')
        if appId != 'shared-id':
           raise endpoints.UnauthorizedException('No, you dont!')

        if not test_model.from_datastore:
            raise endpoints.NotFoundException('testModel not found.')
        return test_model

application = endpoints.api_server([MyApi], restricted=False)
```

My question is: **how do I get at the request object in this line?**

- pwd,keytype = **request**.get_unrecognized_field_info('hiddenProperty')