# GAE Cloud Endpoint not showing 401 auth error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to use authentication to save profile but GAE Endpoint does not give 401 error even if user is null.

Instead Endpoint is responding with 200 ok and giving default results.

BTW this is part of the [Udacity Course](https://www.udacity.com/course/ud859).

```
/**
 * Creates or updates a Profile object associated with the given user
 * object.
 *
 * @param user
 *            A User object injected by the cloud endpoints.
 * @param profileForm
 *            A ProfileForm object sent from the client form.
 * @return Profile object just created.
 * @throws UnauthorizedException
 *             when the User object is null.
 */

// Declare this method as a method available externally through Endpoints
@ApiMethod(name = "saveProfile", path = "profile", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
// The request that invokes this method should provide data that
// conforms to the fields defined in ProfileForm

// TODO 1 Pass the ProfileForm parameter
// TODO 2 Pass the User parameter
public Profile saveProfile(final User user) throws UnauthorizedException {

    String userId = null;
    String mainEmail = null;
    String displayName = "Your name will go here";
    TeeShirtSize teeShirtSize = TeeShirtSize.NOT_SPECIFIED;

    // TODO 2
    // If the user is not logged in, throw an UnauthorizedException
    if(user== null){
        throw new UnauthorizedException("Authorization Required!");
    }
    // TODO 1
    // Set the teeShirtSize to the value sent by the ProfileForm, if sent
    // otherwise leave it as the default value

    // TODO 1
    // Set the displayName to the value sent by the ProfileForm, if sent
    // otherwise set it to null

    // TODO 2
    // Get the userId and mainEmail

    // TODO 2
    // If the displayName is null, set it to default value based on the user's email
    // by calling extractDefaultDisplayNameFromEmail(...)

    // Create a new Profile entity from the
    // userId, displayName, mainEmail and teeShirtSize
    Profile profile = new Profile(userId, displayName, mainEmail, teeShirtSize);

    // TODO 3 (In Lesson 3)
    // Save the Profile entity in the datastore

    // Return the profile
    return profile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28206004/3877822). Go ["Star" this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log&groupby=&sort=&id=8848#makechanges) to get updates on when it's fixed. There are a couple workarounds in the first link, heres a quote from it:

> There are two workarounds (1) save the user and read back from the
>   store, if it refers to a valid account the user id will be populated
>   (this sucks because you pay the saving / loading / deletion cost for
>   each API access that is authenticated even if it is tiny, and
>   obviously some performance cost) and (2) you could use the google+ ID
>   but that is NOT the same as the user id.